# What is the Weyl algebra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, mathematical-physics, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I have a question about Weyl algebras. It arose reading [this](https://arts.units.it/retrieve/handle/11368/2908071/187269/upload.pdf) (page 30) and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02752) (page 11), but I think the physical context is not very important, so I can summarize here what they say. They consider an algebra $H$ spanned by the basis $\{x_1, ..., x_n\}$. This is the algebra of single-particle operators. Each element in $H$ is written as $x_r= \vec{r} \cdot \vec{x} =  \sum_{\mu=1}^n r_\mu x_\mu$. Furthermore, $H$ is equipped with a bilinear antisymmetric form $\sigma$ (some commutator of operators). If $\sigma$ is non-degenerate, then $H$ becomes a symplectic vector space. Then, they say, $H$ supports a bosonic algebra: the Weyl algebra $\mathcal{W} (H, \sigma)$ generated by the Weyl operators $W(\vec{r})$, which satisfy the relations

$$ W(\vec{r_1}) W(\vec{r_2}) = W(\vec{r_1}+\vec{r_2}) e^{-\frac{i}{2} \vec{r_1} \cdot \sigma \cdot \vec{r_2}},\\
W^\dagger (\vec{r}) = W(-\vec{r}) = W^{-1}(\vec{r}).$$

I understand each thing on its own, but I don't know what it means that "$H$ supports a Weyl algebra". I mean $H$ is an algebra itself, the algebra of operators. What does it mean for an algebra or a symplectic vector space to support another algebra? Is it related to some group? And, if $H$ represents the algebra of operators, what does its algebra $\mathcal{W}$ represent? They cite [this](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540170938) reference book, in which all this is probably explained. But it seems long and I would appreciate a simpler explanation/reference for this.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93970/what-is-the-weyl-algebra-of-a-confined-bosonic-particle?rq=1). Crudely "supports" means the Heisenberg-like Lie algebra of phase-space, *H*, can be summarized by the exponentiated, so Lie group, braiding relations specifying the Weyl algebra. Start with finite matrices, like the [clock-and-shift ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Construction:_The_clock_and_shift_matrices).

Comment: For concrete GL(N) examples, see [this](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.528788).